# Get selected item in listbox and call another function storing the selected for it

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a canvas that calls `createCategoryMeny(x)` when it is clicked.

This function just creates a `Toplevel()` window,

```
def createCategoryMenu(tableNumber):

    ##Not interesting below:
    categoryMenu = Toplevel()
    categoryMenu.title("Mesa numero: " + str(tableNumber))
    categoryMenu.geometry("400x400+100+100")

    categoryMenu.focus()
    categoryMenu.grab_set()

    Label(categoryMenu, text="Elegir categoria \n Mesa numero: " + str(tableNumber)).pack()


    ## RELEVANT CODE BELOW:
    listbox = Listbox(categoryMenu, width=50, height=len(info.listaCategorias))
    listbox.pack(pady=20)

    for item in info.listaCategorias:
        listbox.insert(END, item)

    listbox.selection_set(first=0)

    ##My attempt to solve it
    callback = lambda event, tag= "ThisShouldBeTheSelected!!": do(event, tag)
    listbox.bind("<Double-Button-1>", callback)
```

Then the do function:

```
def do(event, tag):
    print tag
```

This successfully prints `"ThisShouldBeTheSelected!!"``.

And this is where I am utterly stuck.

I cant get the double clicked element (the selected one).

I want to pass it as `tag=`.

I have tried:

```
listbox.curselection()
```

Which always prints `('0',)`

If I remove `listbox.selection_set(first=0)`, I only get this: `()`

So the questions are:

- How can I get the selected item (the double clicked one)
- (Not so important) Is it reasonable to pass it to the other function like I do?

---

Note:

I found [this](http://tcl.sourceforge.net/faqs/tk/#listbox/curselection):

> **8.5. Why doesn't .listbox curselection or selection get return the
>   proper item when I make a button binding to my listbox?**
>
> The best way to get the selected item during a button click event on a
>   listbox is to use the following code:
>
> bind .listbox  { set item [%W get [%W nearest %y]] }
>
> This ensures that the item under the pointer is what will be returned
>   as item. The reason .listbox curselection can fail is because the
>   items in curselection are not set until the Listbox class binding
>   triggers, which is after the instance bindings by defaults. This is
>   the same reason for which selection get can fail, but it will also
>   fail if you set the -exportselection option to 0.

I'm not sure if it's helpful, I don't really understand what it is saying.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For one, don't use `lambda`. It's useful for a narrow range of problems and this isn't one of them. Create a proper function, they are much easier to write and maintain.

Once you do that, you can call `curselection` to get the current selection.  You say you tried that but your example code doesn't show what you tried, so I can only assume you did it wrong.

As for the rather unusual advice to use `nearest`... all it's saying is that bindings you put on a widget happen before default bindings for that same event. It is the default bindings that set the selection, so when you bind to a *single* button click, your binding fires before the selection is updated by the default bindings. There are many ways around that, the best of which is to *not* bind on a single click, but instead bind on `<<ListboxSelect>>` which will fire after the selection has changed.

You don't have that problem, however. Since you are binding on a double-click, the selection will have been set by the default single-click binding and `curselection` will return the proper value. That is, unless you have your own single-click bindings that prevent the default binding from firing.

Here's a simple example that prints out the selection so you can see it is correct. Run it from the command line so you see stdout:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        lb = tk.Listbox(self)
        lb.insert("end", "one")
        lb.insert("end", "two")
        lb.insert("end", "three")
        lb.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.OnDouble)
        lb.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    def OnDouble(self, event):
        widget = event.widget
        selection=widget.curselection()
        value = widget.get(selection[0])
        print "selection:", selection, ": '%s'" % value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: plus one for <<ListboxSelect>> - I was looking for that kind of event.

Comment: so what should the function look like tbh these answers for me make it more confusing to try and implement

Comment: @GoulouhAnwar: what should _what_ function look like? What function are you talking about?

Comment: "For one, don't use lambda. It's useful for a narrow range of problems and this isn't one of them. Create a proper function, they are much easier to write and maintain."

Comment: @GoulouhAnwar: This answer doesn't use lambda, it very specifically is showing you how to do it with a normal function (`OnDouble`) rather than a lambda. What more do you need to see?

Answer (score 2):

While You have only one listbox to manage with, it's quite good to use something like this (Python 3):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
box = tk.Listbox(root)
box.insert(tk.END, 'First')
box.insert(tk.END, 'Second')
box.insert(tk.END, 'Third')
box.pack()


def onselect(event):
    w = event.widget
    idx = int(w.curselection()[0])
    value = w.get(idx)
    print(value)


box.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onselect)

root.mainloop()
```

But when You add another listbox, or\and meet a situation, where listbox loses its selection, IndexError is raised.
To avoiding it, and to manage different callbacks for different listboxes I suggest something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
box = tk.Listbox(root)
box.insert(tk.END, 'First')
box.insert(tk.END, 'Second')
box.insert(tk.END, 'Third')
box.pack()

box2 = tk.Listbox(root)
box2.insert(tk.END, 'First')
box2.insert(tk.END, 'Second')
box2.insert(tk.END, 'Third')
box2.pack()


def on_first_box(idx, val):
    print('First box idx: %s, value: %s' % (idx, val))


def on_second_box(idx, val):
    print('Second box idx: %s, value: %s' % (idx, val))


def onselect(event, listbox):
    w = event.widget
    try:
        idx = int(w.curselection()[0])
    except IndexError:
        return
    if listbox is box:
        return on_first_box(idx, w.get(idx))
    if listbox is box2:
        return on_second_box(idx, w.get(idx))


box.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda e: onselect(e, box))
box2.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda e: onselect(e, box2))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

For spyder and python 3.6 this following code worked.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("612x417")
root.title("change label on listbox selection")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.configure(background='lightgrey')


#Show selected currency for from in label
frmcur_text = tk.StringVar()
frmcur = tk.Label(root, textvariable=frmcur_text, font="Helvetica 10 bold", anchor='w', background='lightgrey').place(x=195,y=50)

def onselect(evt):
    # Note here that Tkinter passes an event object to onselect()

    w = evt.widget
    index = int(w.curselection()[0])
    value = w.get(index)
#    print ('You selected item %d: "%s"' % (index, value))
    frmcur_text.set(value)

#Create listboxes for xurrency selection
listbox1 = tk.Listbox(root, font="Helvetica 11 bold", height=3, width=10)
listbox2 = tk.Listbox(root, font="Helvetica 11 bold", height=3, width=10)
listbox1.place(x=300,y=50)
listbox2.place(x=300,y=125)


for i in range(20):
    i = i + 1
    listbox1.insert(1, i)
    listbox2.insert(1, i)


listbox1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onselect)    

cs = listbox1.curselection()

frmcur_text.set(cs)

root.mainloop()
```