# Python Method and Classes in GUI Error

Tags: python, tkinter

I am attempting to create a GUI using Python classes.  Because I'm new to Python, I'm still learning to troubleshoot my errors.  Below, I wish to create a class called Plot_Seismo, and create a GUI that has a listbox, a quit button, and a "Plot" button.  I am having trouble with the "Plot_button" within the class.  What I want this button to do is read in the seismogram and then plot the selected seismogram from the listbox.  I have a feeling my syntax is incorrect (due to my naivete).  I can get this to work when this function isn't in a class, but when I put it in a class as a method, I get slightly confused. The error message is shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Tkinter import *
from obspy.core import read
import math


class Plot_Seismo:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.master = parent
        top = Frame(parent, width=500, height=300)
        top.pack(side='top')

        # create frame to hold the first widget row:
        hwframe = Frame(top)
        # this frame (row) is packed from top to bottom (in the top frame):
        hwframe.pack(side='top')
        # create label in the frame:
        font = 'times 18 bold'
        hwtext = Label(hwframe, text='Seismogram Reader GUI', font=('Arial',18,'bold'), fg="red")
        hwtext.pack(side='top')

        ### ListBox
        List1 = Listbox(root, width=50, height= 10)
        List1.insert(1,"trace1.BHZ")
        List1.insert(2,"trace2.BHZ")
        List1.pack(padx=20, pady=20)


        plot_button = Button(top, text='Plot Seismogram', command=self.plot_seis)
        plot_button.pack(side='top', anchor='w', padx=45, pady=20)
        self.event = read(List1.get(List1.curselection()[0]))

        # finally, make a quit button and a binding of q to quit:
        quit_button = Button(top, text='Quit Seismo-Reader GUI', command=self.quit)
        quick_button.pack(side='top', anchor='w', padx=20, pady=20)
        self.master.bind('<q>', self.quit)

    def quit(self, event=None):
        self.master.quit()

    def plot_seis(self, event=None):
        self.event.plot()

root = Tk()
Plot_Seismo = Plot_Seismo(root)
root.mainloop()

Error Message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_seismogram.py", line 46, in <module>
    Plot_Seismo = Plot_Seismo(root)
  File "plot_seismogram.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.event = read(List1.get(List1.curselection()[0]))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? Or is the button just doing nothing?

Comment: I have added the error message above.  I wish to first read the event ( selected from the list) and then use the function plot_seis to plot the seismogram using the plot_button.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I do not have `obspy` module installed, I had to shrink down your code a bit, but you should get the point.

Since I only have Python3 running on my machine, I rewrote your code to Python3 which is not a big deal. The only differences should be (`tkinter` instead of `Tkinter` and `print()` instead of `print`).

I changed some parts of your code: The listbox is no populated using a list, which make this a bit easier and it became a class attribute to access it in `plot_seis`.

Since `.curselection()` returns a tuple with the listboxes entry index, we have to `get` the according text entry as described in the [docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm) and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7617619/3991125).

Buttons and maybe the listbox provide some event handling features which are making the listbox an class attribute by using `self.` kind of ugly somehow, but it does the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

from tkinter import *
# from obspy.core import read
import math


class Plot_Seismo:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.master = parent
        top = Frame(parent, width=500, height=300)
        top.pack(side='top')

        # create frame to hold the first widget row:
        hwframe = Frame(top)
        # this frame (row) is packed from top to bottom (in the top frame):
        hwframe.pack(side='top')
        # create label in the frame:
        font = 'times 18 bold'
        hwtext = Label(hwframe, text='Seismogram Reader GUI', font=('Arial',18,'bold'), fg="red")
        hwtext.pack(side='top')

        ### ListBox
        self.List1 = Listbox(root, width=50, height= 10)
        # populate listbox using a list with desired entries
        self.list_entries = ["trace1.BHZ", "trace2.BHZ"]
        for i, element in enumerate(self.list_entries):
            self.List1.insert(i, element)
        self.List1.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

        plot_button = Button(top, text='Plot Seismogram', command=self.plot_seis)
        plot_button.pack(side='top', anchor='w', padx=45, pady=20)

        # finally, make a quit button and a binding of q to quit:
        quit_button = Button(top, text='Quit Seismo-Reader GUI', command=self.quit)
        quit_button.pack(side='top', anchor='w', padx=20, pady=20)
        self.master.bind('<q>', self.quit)

    def quit(self, event=None):
        self.master.quit()

    def plot_seis(self, event=None):
        selection_index = self.List1.curselection()[0]
        selection_text = self.List1.get(selection_index)
        print(selection_text)

        # do something with `read` from the `obspy.core` module
        # read(selection_text)


root = Tk()
Plot_Seismo = Plot_Seismo(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi Albert, this worked!  It looks like I got hung up on the listbox and forgot to add the 'self' prefix, which was screwing with the seismogram button.  I also appreciate your addition of the for loop, which makes the code more readable.  Again, thanks for your help!  I appreciate it.