# Tkinter Listbox make a selection

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am trying to create a pop-up box to select multiple years. I have the box created but I cannot figure out how to make a button to actually select multiple years. The goal is to take that selection and store it in a list.

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk

test_years = ["2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"]
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Test Year Selection")
lb = Listbox(root, selectmode=MULTIPLE, height = len(test_years), width = 50) # create Listbox
for x in test_years: lb.insert(END, x)
lb.pack() # put listbox on window
root.mainloop()
```

To clarify I am looking to select lets say 2017 and 2018 and have that selection stored in a list using tkinter listbox.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get-selected-item-in-listbox-and-call-another-function-storing-the-selected-for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616541)

Comment: Do you mean that when you select the value in the `Listbox`,it will be appended to a variable `list`?

Comment: Yes,  @jizhihaoSAMA that is what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A example to get the value you select when you press the `Start` button:

```
from tkinter import *
# import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk

def printIt():
    SelectList = lb.curselection()
    print([lb.get(i) for i in SelectList]) # this will print the value you select


test_years = ["2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"]
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Test Year Selection")
lb = Listbox(root, selectmode=MULTIPLE, height = len(test_years), width = 50) # create Listbox
for x in test_years: lb.insert(END, x)
lb.pack() # put listbox on window

tk.Button(root,text="Start",command=printIt).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to add the value of selected item of listbox to a list. you need to call bind() method on the listbox widget. here is the code from this amazing tutorial on [tkinter listbox](https://rawpython.com/tkinter-listbox/)

```
def get_value(event):
    # Function to be called on item click

    # Get the index of selected item using the 'curseselection' method.
    selected = l.curselection()
    if selected: # If item is selected
        print("Selected Item : ",l.get(selected[0])) # print the selected item

# Create a listbox widget
l = Listbox(window)
l.bind('<>',get_value)
l.pack()
```